# Command + f hangs Finder

Tags: finder, performance, search, bug

I just bought a new MacBook Pro running OS X 10.10.3 and then migrated from my old Mavericks MacBook Pro. Now when I search for a file using <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, Finder hangs/beachballs/becomes unresponsive after just a few letters. Here's what I tried and what happened:

1. Removing com.apple.finder.plist or com.apple.dock.plist from `/Users/username/Library/Preferences` then rebooting (as suggested various places such as [here](http://osxdaily.com/2015/04/10/fix-finder-problems-mac-os-x/)) didn't fix the problem.
2. Trashing the contents of `Library/Saved Application State/` then rebooting **did** fix the problem—for exactly one search, subsequent searches had the same problem as before. I deduce that the saved state might be a part of the problem.
3. Restricting the search to PDF or Document before I type search terms also fixes the problem, from which I think that the size of the set of files to be searched might be a part of the problem.

What is causing this situation and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your descriptions, it appears to be an [active bug related to smart search and regular search](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6602756).

On page two of that discussion, one of the posters stated the following:

> Here is what finally fixed for me. I went in mail.app (whose search
>   was totally misbehaving too), and I rebuild all the mailboxes in my
>   accounts. (Select all the folders, "Folder" menu, "rebuild") When this
>   finished, I rebuilt my index again, restarted and... it is working
>   like a charm since then!